# Can Mypy infer that the returned instance is of a subclass

Tags: mypy

The following code

```py
class A:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def copy(self) -> "A":
        return self.construct_self()
    
    def construct_self(self) -> "A":
        return A()


class B(A):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
    
    def copy(self) -> "B":
        return super().copy()
    
    def construct_self(self) -> "B":
        return B()
```

triggers error in mypy: `error: Incompatible return value type (got "A", expected "B")  [return-value]`, although the code is legitimate, and running `B().copy()` will correctly return a `B` instance.

Is it possible for mypy to infer that the returned type for `super(B, B()).copy` is `B`, a subclass of `A`?

I understand it is possible to get rid of this error by (i) changing the return type of `B.copy` to `"A"`, or (ii) simply removing the `B.copy` override. However, by doing either of this, the typing system will no longer realize `B().copy()` is an instance of `B`, and all type-`B`-specific methods will trigger errors.

Scenario: a function (such as `copy`) is designed to distribute the task to actual implementations in subclasses (such as `construct_self`).

Comment: In this case you can just delete the `copy` implementation in `B`, all it does is delegate to the implementation it already had via inheritance. Same with the rest of the methods, in fact, and you can use the [self type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/): [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=3fb22a20bc525d2995a3158997f5a7e8).

Comment: Do you mean [`Self`type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/)? It seems to exactly represent your case: `def copy(self) -> Self`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, in this example I don't really need overriding the methods, but in my actual code different operations are performed. But the `Self` type is what I am looking for, thanks!